# Experiencing problems with UV unwrapping walls containing openings with Archipack addon

Tags: uv

I'm struggling to figure out how i can UV unwrap a wall properly where either a door or window is attached to it.

As shown in the pictures below, the two UV maps are identical, so it seems that blender cant read the autoboolean that Archipack creates in the wall when adding a door or window.

Also, when entering edit mode, picture 2 shows that blender some sort of ignores the window..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does any one of you know how it is possible for me to unwrap the wall properly :-)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Archipack but i suspect the window comes with a  cutout done with a Boolean modifier set to Difference. So at the moment there is no window hole in the wall. Either apply a boolean modifier, if there actually is one. Or model an actual window hole in Edit Mode. Only then can a hole be made/seen in the UV Editor.

Comment: (no hole in the mesh of the window object, i mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that the boolean modifier isn't applied automatically by archipack. Apply it manually and holes will be cut :-)